# How to start selecting at row 2, rather than all rows?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I modify the following to limit the selection to only start at row 2? Currently it selects every row.

```
Set myRng = .Range("D2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
```

Comment: the code you presented selects either rows 1:2 if there is nothing in column D or selects ranged D2:D(last_row_with_data_in_D), isn't it? I don't find it possible to select all rows except you have data until last row in D column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work, you will have to ensure that there is data in cell `D2`. See this example.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Lrow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Get last row which has data in Col D
        Lrow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        If Not Lrow < 2 Then
            Set myRng = .Range("D2:D" & Lrow)
            MsgBox myRng.Address
        Else
            MsgBox "There is no data in cell D2"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```